# Calling a function upon set command

Tags: vim

I'm swapping some mappings on my keyboard to make it easier on my wrist, but I wouldn't want others to be surprised if they open vim on a computer I had been working on.

So I put these mappings inside a function in my `.vimrc` so I can selectively enable the mappings.

My question is, how can I tell vim (in the `.vimrc` file) to call a function if I `:set` a variable?

Something like `:set wrist` and it would call `SwapKeysForWrist`.

---

Note: I know I can give the function a simpler name and call it, for example `:call Shahbaz()`, but that requires me to use <kbd>shift</kbd> three times (besides `:`) which is what I'm trying to avoid. In fact, the function swaps the digits with their alternative keys (since I use those symbols much more often than actual numbers during programming), and typing parentheses (added that I'd be holding shift) does strain my wrist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot define your own `:set` names, you can only use mappings or custom commands.

I would suggest using a custom `:Wrist` command; it's short to type and should be easy for you to remember. If you want to get around the uppercase `W`, you need to use a `:cabbrev` or the [cmdalias plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=746).

Comment: No the shift-W should be fine. Thanks, I'll look into how to do that. It's even shorter, so it's great

Comment: See `:help :command`, basically, it is `:command -bar Wrist call SwapKeysForWrist()`

Comment: Yes I had just done `:command Wrist call ...()`. I would add the `-bar` option in case one day things got more complicated. Thanks again